# How to add label words in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I need to add some words that look like labels as seen in the picture [label example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65oRH.jpg), so basically an enumeration of key-words. Is there a way to do this in Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do it by inserting a rounded corner rectangle shape.

The setting is on the Insert tab. Then pull down the Shapes menu button, and in the group of rectangles, it is the second one.

[image]

Comment: That's a great suggestion! Is there an easy way to deal with distance and alignment of the shapes, if I have 20-30 labels?

Comment: Yes, you select the shapes, and then on the Shape Format tab, you choose the Align menu and pick the alignment option you want. Shapes float on the document surface so you can drag them into position and again, align to your taste.

Comment: One other point, Word has a Grid option, it's on the View tab. You can temporarily turn it on and the fine grid lines will also help you position those shapes on a page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Smart Art if in the Windows version. It is on the Insert tab.

[image: Smart Art in Word]